# FuelCMS how to output navigation items

Tags: php, codeigniter, fuelcms

I already have items in the navigation but when I try to do this:

`var_dump($this->fuel->navigation->render());`

I am not getting any result, meaning a `string '' (length=0)`.

I also trie `fuel_nav()` but it isn't outputting anything.

Is that the proper way to output navigation items in FuelCMS?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe because `render()` is a method that returns *nothing*? What did you expect it to return? It's probably the method which builds the presentation layer of the application.

Comment: @AlanMachado Maybe an array or a list of the navigation items that I have in the admin?

Comment: If you open up Navigation class and look into `function render`, is there any kind of return? I bet you won't find any BUT what you may find, is the origin of the data it uses to **render** your navigation items, and that origin is the place you might query to fetch what you want.

Comment: @AlanMachado I see, i tried this one `fuel_nav()` but still there's no output

Comment: Means you have to go back even... further. I could download the CMS here to find it but unfortunately I'm at a thin client with astronomical TWO GB of storage where 70% is already being used. If you don't find an answer within three hours from now, I'll come back and help you better.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do actually have navigation items created in FUEL right?

If you do and you want to debug the raw array you can have a look at it with:

```
$nav_items = fuel_nav(['return_normalized' => true]);
print_obj($nav_items);
```

This will also do it:

```
$nav_items = $this->fuel->navigation->data();
print_obj($nav_items);
```

If you just want to pound it out to screen, just:

```
<?=fuel_nav()?>
```

will do it.